# How to prevent repeating code using jade conditionals

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I have a common problem with [jade-lang](http://jade-lang.com/) when using conditionals to write different markup.

Here is a simple example where I wrap an element in a `<del>` to render a *deleted user*:

```
if user._destroy
  del
    a.btn-block(href="#", title="Restore user", data-id=user.id)
      strong=user.email
      i.fa.fa-trash.pull-right
else
  a.btn-block(href="#", title="Remove user", data-id=user.id)
    strong=user.email
    i.fa.fa-trash.pull-right
```

The problem is that the code inside the `<a>` is the same in both `if/else` blocks, but since `if` hasn't an `end` I must repeat the code in both. Depending on case, this may lead to a lot of code repeating.

Answer (score 0):

One method I use to prevent repeat code like this is using a [mixin](http://jade-lang.com/reference/mixins/) and pass a block to it.

```
mixin user_email(user)
  if user._destroy
    del
      a.btn-block(href="#", title="Restore user", data-id=user.id)
        block
  else
    a.btn-block(href="#", title="Remove user", data-id=user.id)
      block

+user_email(user)
  strong=user.email
  i.fa.fa-trash.pull-right
```

It solves the problem, but is not really much pretty.